# Ctrl + Shift + t doesn't use current profile when creating a new session in Konsole

Tags: kde

If I create a custom profile in Konsole, and create a shortcut for it on the desktop:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td5Sy.png)

Then if I click on the shortcut it starts Konsole with the 'mds' profile. Everything looks as expected. Then if I start a 'New Tab' using the 'Ctrl + Shift + t' shortcut keys, it doesn't create a new tab with the 'mds' profile, it creates one with the default profile. I can't seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+t opens a new default with default profile (as you can check [here](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/konsole/commandreference.html)). You can define you new profile as default, but if you don't want to do this you can define a shortcut to open your new profile.

To do this open Konsole settings, go to Profiles, select your new profile and double click the area on the column Shortcut. Now you can define your new shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the *Clone Tab* command from the [*File* menu](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/konsole/commandreference.html#file-menu); you can also assign a keyboard shortcut to it, and it should be available in the tab context menu, too.

And if you check the [*Show in Menu* option](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/konsole/profiles.html) for a profile, you'll be able to select it from the *New Tab* submenu.

Or, as Frederico mentioned in his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537687/157411), if that's the only profile you're using you could make it the default.